# Submitting to AppStore: Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21

Tags: ios, swift, logging, app-store

I built an iOS App which I would like to submit to Apple so I can let my co-workers test it. I first cleaned the workspace (I am using CocoaPods) and then archived it.

Then I come in the Archives window and click "Upload to App Store".
The following error occurs: "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" with the following logs:

IDEDistribution.critical.log:

```
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] Failed to generate distribution items with error: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] Presenting: Error Domain=DVTMachOErrorDomain Code=0 "Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=}
```

IDEDistribution.standard.log:

```
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] Beginning distribution assistant for archive: AppName, task: Upload
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] Automatically selecting the only availaable distribution method <IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x7fb7816c36a0>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78240a060:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77ca3fc80:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78126ea00:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78240f980:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/KeychainSwift.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/KeychainSwift.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/KeychainSwift.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c858a0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb7822537e0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SDCAlertView.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SDCAlertView.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SDCAlertView.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c9d520:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cac4420:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cad5570:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78126e6a0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78179c400:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78220caa0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/ReachabilitySwift.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/ReachabilitySwift.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/ReachabilitySwift.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c9e720:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cace260:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for <DVTFilePath:0x7fb7820fa200:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/CrashReporter.framework/Versions/A'>: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/CrashReporter.framework/Versions/A" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/CrashReporter.framework/Versions/A" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
2016-01-07 9:23:36 AM +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant
```

IDEDistribution.verbose.log

```
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78240a060:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Eureka.framework'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77ca3fc80:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77ca3fc80:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftContacts.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78126ea00:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78126ea00:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78240f980:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/KeychainSwift.framework'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c858a0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c858a0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb7822537e0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SDCAlertView.framework'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c9d520:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c9d520:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cac4420:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cac4420:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cad5570:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cad5570:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78126e6a0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78126e6a0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78179c400:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb78220caa0:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/ReachabilitySwift.framework'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb780c9e720:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/SwiftyJSON.framework'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cace260:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] [OPTIONAL] Can't have a profile, not a bundle at <DVTFilePath:0x7fb77cace260:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib'>
2016-01-07 9:23:21 AM +0000 [MT] IDEDistributionItem init <DVTFilePath:0x7fb7820fa200:'/Users/MyUsername/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-07/AppName 07-01-16 10.22 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AppName.app/Frameworks/CrashReporter.framework/Versions/A'>
```

I know there are numerous of questions about this on StackOverflow with different solutions, but none of them have worked for me so far. 
I am using CocoaPods in my App, and also another framework called CrashReporter.framework for QuincyKit.

I hope someone could help me with this.

Comment: Looking at the numerous errors, `"..." did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."`, implies you've not included the required entitlements.

Comment: What does that exactly mean and how can I fix that? The App uses keychain/DataProtection, as I also specified in iTunesConnect.

Comment: I also just tried reinstalling cocoapods with version 3.8.0 instead of 3.9.0, and removing the derivedData of Xcode, but both didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to actually fix the problem, but I got the error away by removing the CrashReporter framework and the QuincyKit_CrashReporter-library from my App.

This is not the solution I was hoping to find, but the only way to get the App in the AppStore in time.

Maybe there is a way to get it working *with* the CrashReporter framework, which I will then post here. Else I will leave it out or find another one.

Answer (score 5):

I also got this error when trying to embed the CrashReporter framework. It turns out that you shouldn't embed the framework. Instead, just add it to your "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". That fixed this issue for me.

Comment: After many hours of headache, this solved my issue. Thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was the Crashlytics.framework

I have to remove it from **General->EmbeddedBinaries** and only had it to **General->[image: LinkedFrameworks and Libraries]**

In a general way, to retrive the error, when you have this window :

Click on **Show logs**

You will find 3 logs files :

- IDEDistribution.critical.log
- IDEDistribution.standard.log
- IDEDistribution.verbose.log

In my case, in **IDEDistribution.standard.log**, the line before Canceled distribution assistant helped me to find the issue :

> 2018-01-12 13:58:55 +0000  [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user
>   entitlements for
>   :
>   Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at
>   "/Users/kevinabrioux/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-01-12/Eyelights
>   12-01-2018
>   14.57.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Eyelights.app/Frameworks/Crashlytics.framework"
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at
>   "/Users/kevinabrioux/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2018-01-12/Eyelights
>   12-01-2018
>   14.57.xcarchive/Products/Applications/Eyelights.app/Frameworks/**Crashlytics.framework"**
>   did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.}
>   2018-01-12 14:13:57 +0000 [MT] **Canceled distribution assistant**

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557090/found-an-unexpected-mach-o-header-code-0x72613c21-in-xcode10-with-fbsdkcorekit for a similar issue and solution

Answer (score 2):

I've been resolved that problem, it's all my fault: I Link Binary Crashlytics.framework[static library] and also Embed Frameworks Crashlytics.framework[static library], so it is just because of duplicate reference.

So I think you should delete Crashlytics.framework from embedded binaries section, because you have this framework link in linked framework.

before deleting any framework please check your log and you will see what is your problem. you can search framework in logs.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are not `Embed & Sign`-ing any static framework.

Check that you are not `Embed & Sign`-ing any framework in a dependency like a framework or an extension.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pods then just do two things.

1. Clean the project
2. Pods De-integrate
   -> pod install again
   This works for me.
   Happy Coding