# Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21 in Xcode10 with FBSDKCoreKit.framework

Tags: javascript, ios, xcode, react-native

I have a project using the latest version of the FacebookSDK and Xcode 10, the project runs OK in devices, but when submitting to the App Store, during during validation the following error occurs:

> Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21.

The log shows:

> 2019-02-04 11:58:57 +0000 [OPTIONAL] Didn't find archived user entitlements for : Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "Item at "/Users/rodrigovalles/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-02-04/AlquilaTuCancha 4-2-19 08.56.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AlquilaTuCancha.app/assets/FBSDKCoreKit.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Item at "/Users/rodrigovalles/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2019-02-04/AlquilaTuCancha 4-2-19 08.56.xcarchive/Products/Applications/AlquilaTuCancha.app/assets/FBSDKCoreKit.framework" did not contain a "archived-expanded-entitlements.xcent" resource.} 2019-02-04 11:59:17 +0000 [MT] Canceled distribution assistant

I have tried deleting frameworks from Embed Frameworks and adding in Link Binary With Libraries, and changing the Mach-O type of the framework. But the error isn't gone

Answer (score 6):

I came across this issue today while adding the FacebookSDK to an iOS project manually, without using CocoaPods.

I am assuming you have downloaded the SDK [directly from Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/componentsdks).

The Facebook frameworks are static frameworks (not dynamic) so the correct way to integrate them is to include each framework in the "Link Binaries With Libraries" build Build Phase for your target, but **nowhere else**. Do not add them to the Embed Frameworks step.

[image: Link Binary with Libraries]

Comment: After following the above we were still running into this issue, but ensuring to remove the FacebookSDK folder from the Copy Bundle Resources build phase solved this error that we were seeing on creating an Adhoc build for distribution. Many thanks @jessedc